# Getting the age of someone based off input of birthdate and current date

Tags: python

so I have this exercise to do where it is asking me to get the age of 
someone, in terms of days, based off an input of their birthdate and current date.
For instance, (2012,1,1,2012,2,28) should return 58
(Also I am not allowed to use any built in time functions). Here is my code so far:

```
def leapyear(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
  age = 0
  months31 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
  months30 = [4,6,9,11]
  while year1 != year2 and month1 != month2 and day1 != day2:
    age += day2
    day2 = 0
    if day2 == 0:
      month2-=1
      if month2 in months31:
        day2 += 31
        month2 -= 1
      if month2 in months30:
        day2 += 30
        month2 -= 1
      if month2 == 2:
        if leapyear(year2):
          day2 += 29
          month2 -= 1
        else:
          day2 += 28
          month2 -= 1
      else: 
        year2 -= 1
        month2 = 12     
  return age
```

Anyways my problem is that whenever I try this function it keeps returning with 0, any help to fix this is appreciated.

EDIT:
Hey guys, so based off of your feedback I understood why my code was taking forever to run so I changed it up so it looks like this now:

```
def leapyear(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
  # Your code here.
  age = 0
  months31 = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
  months30 = [4,6,9,11]
  if day1 != day2:
    age = abs(day2-day1)
    day2 = day1

  if month1 > month2:
    while month1 !=  month2:
      if month2 in months31:
        age += 31
        month2 += 1
      if month2 in months30:
        age += 30
        month2 += 1
      if month2 == 2:
        if leapyear(year2):
          age += 29
          month2 += 1
        else:
          age += 28
          month2 += 1
  else:
    while month1 !=  month2:
      if month2 in months31:
        age += 31
        month2 -= 1
      if month2 in months30:
        age += 30
        month2 -= 1
      if month2 == 2:
        if leapyear(year2):
          age += 29
          month2 -= 1
        else:
          age += 28
          month2 -= 1
  while year1 != year2:
    if leapyear(year2):
      age += 365
      year2 -= 1
    else:
      age += 365
      year2 -= 1

  return age
```

But the only problem is that for certain examples it's working while for others I am getting close to the answer but not the exact answer. Example, for `print(daysBetweenDates(2012, 1, 1, 2012, 2, 28))` I should get 58 when I am getting 56.

Comment: Right now your while loop is checking if _all_ the components are different. It checks if `year2 != year1` *and* `month2 != month1` *and* `day2 != day1`, and the two input years are the same, so that will evaluate to false. I think instead, you want to check if _either_ component is different, because you only need one difference for the dates to not be the same.

Comment: Your right, i'll let you know if I fix it soon.

Comment: The easiest way to do the check would probably be `while [year1, month1, day1] != [year2, month2, day2]` (which you can write longhand with `ands`s and `or`s if you want to). I haven't checked the rest of your logic, but I will note that the check on `if day2 == 0` is redundant because it's been set to `0` in the line immediately before.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to shorten my run time because I did use `while [year1, month1, day1] != [year2, month2, day2]` awhile back and it ran for over 2 minutes before I force stopped it.

Comment: I would be amazed if that equality comparison was the reason behind the time your code was taking. I'm pretty sure it's happening because you're literally counting 1 day at a time - for a 5-year interval you're running through your loop over 1500 times! (I'd still be surprised if that took more than 2 minutes, but perhaps you had a longer interval.) It should be possible to write this in such a way that you first work out the number of full years (to multiply by 365, except for some care needed over leap years), then account for the months, then finally the days. That should run much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off by none! day but this is a better approach you can use to calculate this process. Had a few errors on first calculation, now it runs great! Enjoy :)

```
def leap_year(y):
    if y % 4 == 0 and (y % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
        return True
    return False

def year_to_date(yeah, month, day):
    days = 0
    days += day
    for i in range(0, month - 1):
        if i == 1:
            if leap_year(year):
                days += 28
            else:
                days += 29 
        else:
            days += days_in_month[i]
    return days

def birth_to_new_year(year, month, day):
    days = 0
    days += days_in_month[month - 1] - day
    for i in range(month, 12):
        if i == 1:
            if leap_year(year):
                days += 28
            else:
                days += 29
        else:
            days += days_in_month[i]
    return days

days_in_month = [31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

day = 18 
month = 9 
year = 2018 

birth_day = 20
birth_month = 11
birth_year = 1988

days = 0

for i in range(birth_year + 1, year):
    if leap_year(i):
        days += 366
    else:
        days += 365

days += year_to_date(year, month, day)
days += birth_to_new_year(birth_year, birth_month, birth_day)

print(days)
```

Comment: One error is that you're adding on 355 days for a leap year, rather than 366. (Typo I presume?) Doesn't account on it own for a difference of 97 though.

Comment: @robinzigmond   Good catch see that, updated, currently inebriated but what is making the difference? I was really set on resolving this and I went through many times im missing something I double check the indexes match ranges, it’s something...

Comment: can't say for sure, as I've just got to work and we don't even use Python here and I'm not going to install it just to test this out. 

Just had a quick glance over and I think you the loop inside `birth_to_new_year`should be `for i in range(month-1, 12)` (if I'm correct that the months are given as 1-12, not 0-11.) That would come to much more than a 97 difference over a 30-year period though. Also I think the line `days += day` in `year_to_date` should add `day-1` instead. Could be wrong though - off-by-one errors are annoying and too easy to make :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Off by -1day now, In my checks for leap years I was using `i == 2` which should be `i==1` due to indexing

Comment: @RobinZigmond GOT IT! :)